# Change files while running java program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, conflict

I am running a program that reads information from a specific file. If, while running the program, I change the contents of that file or delete it, will the program not run correctly?

On a similar note, I have a program that creates a file in my workspace. If I run this program and run it again with different parameters while the first run is still going on, will the file that is being created be replace and overwritten?

Comment: A file is "read" at some point by your program.  If you delete the file before that, you'll get either an "open" error and/or a "read" exception.  If you change the file after that, your program will be out of sync with the current file contents.  Since most I/O is buffered, there might be overlay between the time your program initiates the "read()" and when the "read I/O" actually occurs.  BOTTOM LINE: If you expect a program to be in sync with the current contents of the file, then you should ["lock"](http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/file-locking.jsp) that file.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on *how* you read the contents and the OS itself. Usually there is a read buffer, this buffer is filled using the current contents of the file actually served by the OS. If you delete the file while Reading, ususally there will be thrown a `IOException`.

To be relative sure that noone else change the contents (or delete the file) while you read the file, you can use a [**file-lock**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) in java.

The second question depends on timing, a Stream or Reader will have a cursor to the position inside of the file. If the second program successfully replace the file the first program opend but is smaller than the cursor of the first program, there will be thrown a IOException on the next `read`-command of the first program because the cursor is actually *out of file range*.